Importing Data As String & Numbers Show in Scientific Notation
I have a CSV file (that I've named temp.csv) that looks like the following:

When I import this into R using read_csv('temp.csv', col_types = 'cc') both the Group and ID fields are characters, but row #2 appears in scientific notation and I am not able to see all the numbers in the ID field for that record. I want to see 2222222222223 not 2.22E+12.
How can I do this in R?

You have three columns, would col_types = 'ccc' work? Or if you change your printing options options(digits = 20), does that fix it?

Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately options(digits = 20) does not fix it. I am still seeing the ID value for row #2 in scientific notation. And I should have specified that row # is there only to make it easier to reference the records.

Can you provide a reproducible example? I don't understand how a character column gets printed using scientific notation. Try e.g. data.frame(a = "2222222222222222222222222222222222").

I suspect the issue is with the csv file, not with R. When I save a file that looks like that with Excel, that cell gets saved as 2.22222E+12, not as 2222222222223. I was able to get Excel to save in the desired format by formatting the cell as Number with no decimal points instead of as General.
One way to debug this to open the csv file in a text editor. Or to see what R is actually starting with, read in the lines as text with no processing using readLines("tmp.csv").
And a general rule of thumb -- don't use Excel! It is notorious for doing things like this. There unfortunately aren't good alternatives, so if you do have to use Excel, learn as much as you can about the goofy things it does and turn as many of them off as you can.
